# Looking up information from a preceding observation in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with transactions. Among other things the transactions are tagged with a date/time and customer.

```
library(data.table)
transactions <- data.table(trans.id = 1:10,
                           customer.id = c(rep(c('a','b'),3),'c'))
set.seed(42)
transactions[, time := sample(500, 10, T)]
```

For each transaction I want to look up the customer's preceding transaction so I can do things like calculate the time since the last transaction. This is the best I've been able to do...

```
Find.Prior.ID <- function(id.curr) {
  trans.curr <- transactions[trans.id == id.curr]
  time.curr <- trans.curr[, time]
  customer <- trans.curr[, customer.id]
  prior.trans <- transactions[
    time < time.curr & customer.id == customer]
  if (dim(prior.trans)[1] == 0) {return(NA)}
  time.prior <- prior.trans[,max(time)]
  id.prior <- prior.trans[
    time == time.prior,
    trans.id]
  return(id.prior)
}

transactions[, prior.id := unlist(lapply(
  X = trans.id, FUN = Find.Prior.ID))]
```

Once I have `prior.id` populated a simple merge allows me to map in any other info I want. My problem really comes down to run time. This construction has obtrusively long run times. Is there a way to do this faster?

**ANSWER** (specific to example in question)

```
setorder(transactions, time)
transactions[, prior.id:=c(NA,trans.id[-.N]), by=customer.id]
```

Comment: Does   `transactions[,prior.id:=c(NA,trans.id[1:(.N-1)]),by=customer.id]` create correctly the `prior.id` column?

Comment: @nicola one can just use `-.N` as in `transactions[,prior.id:=c(NA,trans.id[-.N]),by=customer.id]`

Comment: I've tweaked the example to demonstrate some caveats in Nicola's idea (one of which David's code addresses). If one of you cares to post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5):

In `data.table` version `1.9.5` there is a new `shift` function that takes the argument `type = lag` for calculating the lagged variable.

```
transactions[, prior.id := shift(trans.id, type = "lag"), by = customer.id]
```

Comment: `type = "lag"` is the default so no need to specify it I guess.

Comment: It looks like 1.9.5 hasn't be released to CRAN yet?

Comment: You can install it from [github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)